# Stagnant Air Deep Inside Vintage Mines

Tags: everyday-life, aerodynamics, ideal-gas

This is really a question more about mining ventilation than true "physics."

I occasionally explore a southwest desert mine, but am aware of the hazards - typically passing over half a dozen vintage mines as unsafe (including anything vertical) before finding one stable enough and acceptable for exploration. (I won’t call it “safe”….just acceptable.) My understanding is that, the air in desert mines is usually unproblematic. But should running water - and certainly stagnant water - be present, the presence of harmful $CO_2$ pockets from plant/algae respiration or decomposition should be acknowledged. Carbon monoxide can be an issue as well, something I usually associate with combustion (miners' carbide illumination, wooden torch illumination, primitive engines), but perhaps there are other $CO$ sources in a mine that I'm unaware of. Unlike natural caves which often have multiple inlets, mines with single entrances have no opportunity for flow-through air ventilation. But they nonetheless often have unhindered mountainside openings which are exposed to decades of windstorms. I'm curious, when we are $200$ ft. deep within a hypothetical dry desert mine with one unhindered opening, wouldn't the air deep inside the mine essentially be unchanged from 1930, with the original respiration and combustion products fully present (though a little diluted)?

Secondly, while that may be POSSIBLE, how LIKELY is this situation?

(I assume gas monitors have possibly provided general Yes/No answers to this question over the decades.)

Comment: +1, problems like this including mines etc.. **is** the most **real physics** (and certainly practical) one would ask

Comment: Huh. I'm new to this website and this is a first for me.  Someone (other than me) actually rewrote my original post above. Not just "corrected" aspects of it...but essentially rewrote it. Bizarre...

Comment: @user47362 He certainly intended to keep the original meaning (of one main question) in a better way. I think (did not check edit history) the rewrite is saying how he understood it. Someone took the time to keep the essential question, but trying to make it better. The question meaning is relevant here, not who wrote it. It's still yours, you get the reputation. It's in no way personal. And it's ok to roll back a change in the edit history,. The edit means it was not the ideal format, which is hard to get right in the first question, but the question was so good as to be worth a full rewrite!